# SQL: using group by concat()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which returns result of number of calls made by customers and some suggestions made for customers and etc.. for that particular date ie... grouping it by date

But now I want to find number of customers I tried grouping by `lead_id` and `cuncat(lead_id,timecreatredFormat)` still there is a data mismatch

Below is the query that I have tried

```
    select 
    sum(t.enquiry_cnt),
    sum(t.suggested_cnt),
    sum(t.tot_cnt)

from
    (select 

        case
                when source = 1 then 1
                else 0
            end enquiry_cnt,

            case
                when source = 6 then 1
                else 0
            end suggested_cnt,
            case
                when (source = 1 || source = 6) then 1
                else 0
            end tot_cnt,
             date_format(timecreated, '%d-%b-%Y') created_time,
            lead_id,timecreated
    from
        mg_lead_suggested_listing  group by  concat(created_time,lead_id)   ) t
group by  t.created_time
order by t.timecreated desc
limit 10;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just use **group by lead_id, DATE(timecreated)** ?

Comment: it is helpful if you can post structure of tables used in query and required output format. Remove group by concat(created_time,lead_id) and add COUNT(t.lead_id) in select. may be it works

Comment: thanks for your repays @ StanislavL: no its not working for some condition it work's but in some cases it fail's

@Sandeep: will try posting structure of table 
Note COUNT(t.lead_id) in select will not work becz i need to get count by certain condition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether following query is correct or not. I have added COUNT(DISTINCT t.lead_id) to get customer count.

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE
(
    [source] INT,
    lead_id INT,
    timecreated DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES (1,1,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES (6,1,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES (6,1,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES (1,2,DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES (1,1,DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES (1,1,DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()))


SELECT
    CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE) [date],
     SUM(t.enquiry_cnt) enquiry_cnt,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id) FROM @TEMP WHERE CAST(timecreated AS DATE) = CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE) AND [source] = 1) as lead_enquiry_cnt,
    SUM(t.suggested_cnt) suggested_cnt,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id) FROM @TEMP WHERE CAST(timecreated AS DATE) = CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE) AND [source] = 6) as lead_suggested_cnt,
    SUM(t.tot_cnt) tot_cnt,
    COUNT(t.lead_id) as lead_cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN [source] = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END enquiry_cnt,
        CASE
            WHEN [source] = 6 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END suggested_cnt,
        CASE
            WHEN ([source] = 1 OR [source] = 6) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END tot_cnt,
        lead_id,
        timecreated
    FROM
        @TEMP
    ) AS t
group by  
    CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE)
order by 
    [date] desc
```

Comment: :thanks but i want how many customers are there in   enquiry_cnt, ie.. how many unique id lead_id is present under   enquiry_cnt for egg if there are 10 enquirers  and 2 customers made 10 enquirers  i want 2 as count 

hope u got it

anyways  good work :-)

Comment: @ManjuKb check now i have added new fields in select